# How to perform selector in C# like in the Objective C?

Tags: c#, objective-c

1. As we know, in Objective C, we can use code like
   `id myClone = [anObject performSelector:@selector(unknownMethod)];`
   to **send a message to an object** ,even if we don't know if the object has a implementation or not.  But I don't know how to do that in C#.
2. I've already know that we can also use delegate grammar in C# like in the Objective C, but I can't find any concepts in C# just like the protocol in Objective C.

Could you give me any tips? Just some key word please:-)

Comment: Disclaimer: I don't know objective-c, so I post this as a comment. You may be looking for the [dynamic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx) keyword? So the c# code would be `id myClone = ((dynamic)anObject).unknownMethod();`

Comment: It helps, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Use [reflection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). This approach allows you to handle the case where `anObject` doesn't have the method you're looking for.

```
Type t = anObject.GetType();
MethodInfo method = t.GetMethod("UnknownMethod");
object result = method.Invoke(anObject, new object[] { [...Parameters...] });
```

2) Use the [`dynamic`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx) type.  Of course this means that type safety is only enforced at runtime, and you may incur some performance penalties.

```
object getValue(dynamic obj)
{
    return (object)obj.UnknownMethod([...Parameters...]);
}
```

3) Make `anObject` implement an interface.  Then you can do `((ISomething)anObject).UnknownMethod([...])`  Of course this assumes that you own the code creating `anObject`.

4) Cast to the appropriate type and execute the method.

```
object getValue(object anObject)
{
    if (anObject is MyType1) ...
    else if (anObject is MyType2) ...
}
```

Whichever method you choose, keep in mind that they all have drawbacks.  Reflection may require some tweaking to get the method selected.

Comment: Thank you very much! It really helps me a lot.

Answer (score 2):

[MethodInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
MethodInfo m = ... get the desired method here ...
m.Invoke(anObject, new object[] { ... parameters... });
```

Comment: It helps, thks a lot:-)

Answer (score 1):

Use MethodInfo from Type:

```
MethodInfo info = anObject.GetType().GetMethod("aMethod");
info?.Invoke(args);
```