# How to use @selector in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

Now I want to  implement some functions in my xamarin.iOS projecs . 
I have found the solution but implemented in Objective-C.And it used the keyword `@selector(...)` .  I found [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32187743/how-to-perform-selector-in-c-sharp-like-in-the-objective-c) as refer.However,as @theB said,use the dynamic type. Of course this means that type safety is only enforced at runtime, and you may incur some performance penalties.SO is there a better way to implement it？ Any suggestion is welcome.Thanks！

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`@selector` is available in xamarin.iOS. It is included in the namespace `ObjCRuntime`.For example ,you can bind click action for a `UIButton`.Just like in Objective-C.

```
using ObjCRuntime;
. . .

UIButton button = new UIButton()
  {
    //. . .
  };
button.AddTarget(this, new Selector("ButtonClickAction:"),UIControlEvent.TouchUpInside);


[Export("ButtonClickAction:")]  
public void ButtonClickAction(UIButton sender)
{
  // . . .
}
```

> [Export("ButtonClickAction:")]

It is important.Members with an `[Export]`, making it possible for Objective-C to access them.For more details you can refer the [docuemnt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/internals/objective-c-selectors).