# iOS selector in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, accessibility, selector

I am trying to create an `UIAccessibilityCustomAction` in Xamarin.iOS. This method require `name, target, selector` as arguments (as you can see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/uikit.uiaccessibilitycustomaction?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12)). The problem is with the `selector` argument.

In Xcode (using Swift) I can easily implement it like this:

```
let up = UIAccessibilityCustomAction(name: "Increment", target: self, selector: #selector(increment))


@objc private func increment() -> Bool{
    //selector implementation
}
```

In Xamarin (using C#) I tried that:

```
UIAccessibilityCustomAction up = new UIAccessibilityCustomAction(name: "Increment", target: iospage, selector: new Selector("Increment"));
```

And its being said that `Selector` can take both a `String` or a `IntPtr` as argument. Since I have no idea what `IntPtr` is and how should I use it, I tried to use the `String` parameter, as you can see above, and I tried to implement the selector like this, following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52659151/how-to-use-selector-in-xamarin-ios).

```
[Export("Increment")]
    private void Increment()
    {
        //selector implementation
    }
```

Problem is that seems like this method never got called (i tried to make it log something when the UIAccessibilityCustomAction is called, but no log is shown), probably because it is the wrong way to implement it.

Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: What is `iospage` ? You have to set the current viewcontroller  as target so that you can get custom method invoke inside it , try to change `iospage` to `this` .

Comment: iospage is actually an istance of a viewcontroller, the problem is only for the selector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UIAccessibilityCustomAction has another instantiate method which you can pass an custom action into it .

```
 UIAccessibilityCustomAction c = new UIAccessibilityCustomAction("Increment", 
        (UIAccessibilityCustomAction customAction) =>
        {

               //selector implementation
        });
```

Comment: Ok thanks, I tried your solution but, sorry for my ignorance, it said that I needed to use a `Func< UIAccessibilityCustomAction, bool >`, which I am not sure how to use. Anyway, I found another instantiate method using ` actionHandler` that has just a `bool` return type, so it's easier to handle. Thanks for your answer anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the tip of @Cole Xia - MSFT, I found another instantiate method that seems to be easier to handle, using only `name, actionHandler`, so without a `target` and `selector`. `actionHandler` is easier to use, cause it's only a function that needs a bool return type.

My implementation:

```
UIAccessibilityCustomAction up = new UIAccessibilityCustomAction("Increment", actionHandler: Increment);

private bool Increment(UIAccessibilityCustomAction customAction)
{
    //implementation of the handler
}
```

Comment: The way is the same as mine , it is just lambda inside the method .

Comment: @ColeXia-MSFT Oh ok, again, sorry for my ignorance but I never use lambda syntax. Thank you!